# Ruby gem 'mongo' insert number as long

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm using `mongo` gem in ruby and i want to insert some record and i want the value to be stored as `NumberLong`

Via mongo ssh console I can do something like this
`db.somecoll.insert({"key" : NumberLong("123456789"})`

and when I'll use find I'll get that field as `NumberLong`.
How can I do the same insert query via `mongo` ruby gem?

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too late, but this is for someone who stumble on this question.

```
db.somecoll.insert({"key" : BSON::Int64.new(123456789)})
```

See https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongodb/bson-ruby/BSON for other BSON types.